# Switching from KDE Plasma to Gnome function keys don't work

Tags: gnome, 20.04, plasma, function-keys

The title suggest it all. I have two DE installed KDE Plasma and Gnome. But the function keys work in KDE but when I switch to Gnome the don't work. What may be to possible reason and how can I fix it.